# How do I set a checkbox in Java to a specific condition if checked or unchecked?

Tags: java

I couldn't seem to find an answer to this on here even though it should be quite basic.

I figured it was a simple process like in other languages (I'm new to Java) and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to allow the user to select if they want the program on top of other windows or not.  It should update as soon as it is checked - not when a button is pressed.

```
if (cbOnTop.isSelected() == true)

{       

     frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

}

else

    {           

         frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

    }
```

Comment: what is your button do that can make the program on top of other windows?

Comment: You need to show how you trigger this code. Also, the `else` doesn't need to recheck the condition. i.e. `if (cbOnTop.isSelected()) { ... } else { ... }` or even `frame.setAlwayOnTop(cbOnTop.isSelected())`

Comment: Ok, I guess that is where I'm confused.  In VB.Net or C# the IF statement just triggers automatically when the condition is met - cbOnTop.isSelected() = true.  How would I go about doing that in Java?

Comment: The isSelected function does not execute when you click a checkbox. It's just a method you can call at any point to discover whether the checkbox is checked. You may need to look into events and listeners. In your listener, you will need something like `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)`

Comment: @John3136, very nice concept... :)